# qml listview image caching doesn't work as expected

Tags: image, qt, listview, caching, qml

I created an list view with images which automatically requests new items when scrolled down. I am using Image component to show the image from url source. the problem is that the images are not cached in memory once they are loaded. I can see them when I scroll down but when I go back up I have to wait for them to be loaded again. Is there a way to fix this? Image component has a property cache but it doesn't do any improvement. I know that in Android this is done in exactly the same way and the images are persisted in memory once downloaded.
here is a sample code:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    id: rootId

    property url fullImageUrl
    property string tag : "windsurfing"

    XmlListModel{
        id : modelId
        namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace media = 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/';"
        source: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=rss2&tags="+tag
        query: "//item[title and media:thumbnail and media:content]"
        XmlRole{name:"fullImage"; query:"media:content/@url/string()" }
    }

    TextField{
        id : userValueId
        font.pointSize: 14
        width: parent.width
        height : implicitHeight
        placeholderText: "Enter a Flickr Tag"
        onEditingFinished: tag = text
    }

    ListView{
        id : listViewId
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: userValueId.height + 10

        Layout.minimumWidth: 400
        Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width - 50
        model: modelId
        delegate:  delegateId
    }

    Component{
        id: delegateId
        Rectangle{
            id :itemId
            height : 300
            width : 500
            Image{
                id : imageId
                source : fullImage
                anchors.fill: parent
                fillMode: Image.Stretch
                cache: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I cache the graphic items supplied by the model and drawn in
>   QML ListView?

I would try to use ListView [cacheBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#cacheBuffer-prop) property which is specified in pixels to fit delegates. If your delegate is of 300 pixels in the scroll direction (say, height and you scroll vertically) then having one delegate per row and 10000 pixels for the "cache buffer" it fits up to 33 delegates then.

```
ListView {
    id : listViewId
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.topMargin: userValueId.height + 10
    cacheBuffer: 10000 // pixels in direction of scrolling the view,
                       // saves a bit of processing just by caching
                       // delegates content in memory, causes async
                       // read-ahead for images outside of view area
    Layout.minimumWidth: 400
    Layout.maximumWidth: parent.width - 50
    model: modelId
    delegate: delegateId
}
```

If the amount of memory strictly limited it makes sense to specify reasonably small cacheBuffer e.g. 2 pages of list view to prevent too much read-ahead. The cache is not a guarantee that the data won't be read again. *I also had some doubts if using Component is the right way to go with image caching but concluded it should not affect things as long as there is no Loader in the code for that Component that does the load at arbitrary times.*

And you can also try to implement own [image provider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) in C++ to explicitly control the image download / caching so the logic will be fully controlled by your code.